# Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension of lines in the plane

Tags: co.combinatorics, st.statistics, discrete-geometry, learning-theory

I'm having some problems with this problem concerning VC dimensions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension), I hope for some helping input.

Given a set $L$ of $n$ lines in the plane, define a hypergraph $H=(L,S)$ such that its vertices are the lines and a subset $l$ of $L$ belongs to $S$ iff there exist points $p$ and $q$ such that all lines in $l$ lie between $p$ and $q$, what is the VC dimension of $H$?

Now, I've managed to show the VC dimension is at least 5, I basically found a group of 5 lines with 4 of them being parallel to each other with differing lengths and the fifth being perpendicular to the four.
but I can't think of a solid proof why it shouldn't be more than 5 (it might be more, it's a bit confusing to me).

Comment: You are more likely to get good answers here if (a) you define what you mean by Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension, and (b) how you showed that the VC dimension of your hypergraph is at least 5.

Comment: Posted a week ago to math.stackexchange, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149369/vapnik-chervonenkis-dimension-of-lines-in-the-plane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, a subset $l$ of lines belongs to $S$ if and only if there is a straight-line segment crossing exactly the lines from $l$.

The problem is then equivalent to the following dual version:

> What is the maximum VC-dimension of a finite set of points in the plane, with respect to the double-wedges that do not contain the origin?

Where by "double-wedge" I mean the union of two opposite regions of the plane between two crossing lines.

It is easy to see that a set of $6$ points in convex position cannot be shattered. Since every set of $17$ points in convex position contains a convex $6$-gon, the VC-dimension is at most 16.

The next step could be investigating all configurations of $6$ points plus the origin if there is some configuration that can be shattered.

[The answer was edited after Gjergji's comment.]

---

One can, indeed, show that the VC-dimension is at most $10$ by a counting argument outlined by Gjergji.
A pair of faces containing the endpoints of the segment determines the subset $l$. For lines in general position, there are $${1+{n+1 \choose 2} \choose 2}$$
pairs of faces, which is still more than $2^n-1$ for $n=11$. But some of the subsets $l$ were overcounted: every $1$-element set was counted $n-1$ times and every $2$-element set at least twice, so we can subtract $3/2 \cdot n(n-1)$. In this way, we get an upper bound $2046$ for the number of subsets $l$ for $n=11$, which is just enough to show that the VC-dimension is at most $10$. Further improvements are possible, for example by considering overcounted triples or by considering the faces with more than $3$ vertices (using
[this](http://www.springerlink.com/content/gl3p7q16787p6428/) result).

---

**Edit:** According to [P. Brass, W. Moser, J. Pach, Research Problems in Discrete Geometry, Chapter 8.2](https://doi.org/10.1007/0-387-29929-7_9) or [MathSciNet, MR1274574](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1274574),
Harborth and Möller [1] proved that every simple arrangement of $9$ pseudolines in the projective plane contains a subarrangement of six pseudolines with a hexagonal face. No such arrangement can be shattered: a triple of pseudolines determined by every other edge of the hexagonal face cannot be crossed by a pseudosegment that avoids the other three pseudolines. This shows that the VC-dimension is at most $8$, even in the stronger setting of pseudolines in the projective plane.

[1]: H. Harborth and M. Möller, Esther Klein problem in projective plane, J. Combin. Math. Combin. Comput. 15 (1994), 171--179. [Zbl 0807.51008](https://zbmath.org/0807.51008).

Comment: Jan, I'm not so convinced by this dual picture, because it has the property that if you can pick a subset of points with a double wedge, then you can also pick it's complement. The original problem doesn't have this property.

Comment: I see... Thank you for pointing this out. The problem is that the wedges that are dual to the segments should not contain the origin. I am editing the answer accordingly. The dual version with arbitrary double-wedges would be equivalent to the original version for arrangements of lines in the projective plane.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 3):

If you take six lines forming the Star of David, then it is impossible to split the lines forming one large triangle from the lines forming the other one.

---

**EDIT.** Oh sorry, I misunderstood the concept. If I do understand it correctly now, the dimension is at least 6: on the picture below the 6 lines can be split in any way.

[image: 6lines] [(source)](http://iibogdanov.narod.ru/6lines.jpg)

---

**EDIT2.** It is not an example, as Gjergji and Cain notice below.

Comment: By the way, what happens in $d$ dimensions? The same example shows that $VC\leq 2d-1$...

Comment: Those six lines are a good example of a groupthat cannot be shattered. But in order to prove that the VC dimension is indeed bounded by 6, It is neccesary to show that every group of size 6 cannot be shattered. 

Comment: Sorry; I have added an example of a good 6-tuple of lines.

Comment: The obvious upper bound on the VC-dimension is 10. We have quite a gap here...

Comment: Btw, your example of six lines doesn't seem to work. How can you split the three lines which form the smallest triangle from the other three?

Comment: What makes 10 an obvious upper bound?

Comment: @Gjergji: a point in an upper-right triangle having a common vertex with our one, and a point from the lower pentagon sharing a side with our triangle.

Comment: @Ilya, I meant the opposite partition, a line segment which doesn't intersect precisely those three lines. @Cain, the number of regions is $O(n^2)$ and so the number of subsets of lines between some two points is $O(n^4)$, with explicit constants. Now this must be at least $2^n$,  for $n=dim_{VC}$, so you get a bound that I can't improve past $\le 10$.

Comment: @Gjergji: It seemed to me that for any partition of our set into two subsets there is a pair of points which DISTINGUISHES these subsets - in one of two converse ways. Yes, there is an ambiguity in the definition, since the provided link does not discuss the hypergraphs; so I would like to ask Cain to clarify what exactly does he mean...

BTW, If my interpretation is correct, the upper bound increases...

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen VC dimension interpreted that way. _Shattering_ is more restrictive than _distinguishing_.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shattering_(machine_learning)

Comment: @Ilya: well, a subset $v$ of vertices such that |$v$|=$n$ (the 6 lines in your example) is said to be shattered if you can get every possible subset of $v$ by intersecting $v$ with edges of the hypergraph. meaning you have $2^n$ distinct intersections. in your 6 lines example, i cant think of a hyperedge interesecting with the 6 lines that would result in the 3 lines not consisting of the small triangle, so this is not a shattered group, and it doesnt show that the VC dimension might be 6. 

Comment: OK, sorry. I would like to keep this answer - just to show what is wrong...